# Quantum Mechanical description of chiral molecule

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-electrodynamics, hamiltonian-formalism, physical-chemistry, chirality

I am a theoretical physicist by training and I need to consider polarized light interacting quantum mechanically with a single molecule of sugar. I have never done theoretical chemistry and really need advice on where to start, literature, articles... Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can start by reading Organic Chemistry by Morrison-Boyd or LG Wade just to grasp a good understanding on Optical activity and it's working , if that's what you are looking for . These books are also good if you want to learn the basics/in detail of organic chemistry in general . 
I can only suggest this much since I'm a student but I have used the books to study optical activity and they are quite good in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

The text first below looks authoritative.

1. Molecular Light Scattering and Optical Activity, Lawrence Barron, Cambridge Press (2004). Table of contents available [here.](http://assets.cambridge.org/97805211/21378/frontmatter/9780521121378_frontmatter.pdf)
2. Gorin et al., J. Chem. Physics, Optical Activity of the Sugars, **7**, 327 (1939). A fair number of subsequent citations.